# Loading local KML using GoogleEarth plugin from VB.NET through FC.GEPluginCtrls

Tags: vb.net, google-earth-plugin

I'm trying to develop on VB.NET (VS2010) an application that uses the GEPlugin (https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/).

Of course, I've been able to load the plugin into a form and it works. I can see the earth on the plugin, and the user can move across it. But now I'm trying to load a local kml file into the plugin, using the KmlTreeView, but without success.

I can load into the plugin external kml files, like "http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/OnEarth_BMNG.kml", using the following code:

```
Private Sub GeWebBrowser1_PluginReady(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FC.GEPluginCtrls.GEEventArgs) Handles GeWebBrowser1.PluginReady

    KmlTreeView1.SetBrowserInstance(GeWebBrowser1)
    GeWebBrowser1.FetchKml("http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/OnEarth_BMNG.kml")

End Sub

Private Sub GeWebBrowser1_KmlLoaded(sender As Object, e As FC.GEPluginCtrls.GEEventArgs) Handles GeWebBrowser1.KmlLoaded
    Dim kml As Object

    kml = e.ApiObject

    GeWebBrowser1.ParseKmlObject(kml)
    KmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(kml)
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GeWebBrowser1.LoadEmbeddedPlugin() ' load the plugin
End Sub
```

However, I don't find the way to load a local kml file. I have checked that exists a method of the GeWebBrowser control that should allow this: GeWebBrowser1.FetchKmlLocal("local path"). But it does't work.

Anyone has used this library?, and if so, has loaded a local kml file successfully?

May be I'm using an old library version (1.010)?. I don't find on the web the release version, and I've not been able to create the release version because I get an error when I try to load the solution.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the inbuilt server to work with local kml files.

See https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/GEServer

```
namespace ServerTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using FC.GEPluginCtrls;
    using FC.GEPluginCtrls.HttpServer;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // initialise the server and tell it where the
        // root directory is 
        private GEServer server = new GEServer("webroot");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // the server is fully configurable...
            // server.RootDirectory = "/foo/bar/";
            // server.DefaultFileName = "bat.kml"
            // server.IPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Any;
            // server.Port = 80;

            // start the server
            server.Start();

            // load the plugin
            geWebBrowser1.LoadEmbededPlugin();

            // when the plug-in has loaded
            geWebBrowser1.PluginReady += (o, e) =>
            {
                // load the kml from the local server
                geWebBrowser1.FetchKml("http://localhost:8080/KML_Samples.kml");
            };

            geWebBrowser1.KmlLoaded += (o, e) =>
            {
                // add the kml to the plugin
                geWebBrowser1.ParseKmlObject(e.ApiObject);
            };
        }
    }
```